# EGIT - after merging the second time still got same conflicts

Tags: git, svn, merge, egit

After i did a merge of branch#1 into the master branch- I got some conflicts, so ive fixed them and committed the changes.

now, if i execute the merge again, i dont get a "already up to date" message, but instead im getting all the conflicts back.

any ideas?

Comment: Did you `git add` or `git rm` the solved conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

After solving the merge conflicts right click on the project go to `Team > Add to Index` then add all the files then commit.

Refer this [video](http://youtu.be/KfeqnernMmE).

Comment: already done that ofcourse, we use egit daily for the last 6 months

Comment: Then after committed run `git status master` command and check whether any changes still needs to be committed. It happens sometimes that eclipse "Staging Area" view doesn’t show any changes but `git status master` returns some changes. In that case use `git add` command then `git commit master`. Then check the result in GUI.

Comment: Im using a bear repository, so i cant really execute this command:(